# How can you use constructor chaining while :base() exist?

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0

The constructor on Square requires to set its own parameter and the parameter inherit from the parent class Polygon.

```
class Polygon
{
    public int NumSides;

    public Polygon(int numSides)
    {
        NumSides = numSides;
    }
}

class Square : Polygon 
{

    public int SideLength; 

    public Square (int sideLength) : this(numSides) : base(numSides)
    {
        SideLength = sidelength; 
        NumSides = NumSides; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `NumSides = NumSides;` What does it mean?

Comment: Are you wondering how you should call the base constructor?

Comment: NumSides  = number of sides.

Comment: What is `: this(numSides)` meant to be doing in `Square`? Using `this` in that position is usually used to invoke a different constructor - but this appears to be trying to call the *same* constructor, which even if it worked would just produce a stack overflow.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. The constructor of class Square is not correct. `this(numSides)` call itself again and again and never get out of that loop. I will go in infinite loop and break with StackOverFlowException.

Comment: Chetan Ranpariya - May be its more of a language issue for you! Its a clear enough. I am asking - How to do constructor chaining while HAVING to use :base. I don't know how else you want me to put it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Square (int sideLength) 
        //: this(numSides)   // would call this ctor again, an endless loop
          : base(4)          // because a square has 4 sides
{
    SideLength = sidelength; 
    // NumSides = NumSides;  // action already taken in the base class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to be passed to the base class must be part of the ctor of the child class:

```
class Square : Polygon {

    public int SideLength; 

    public Square (int sideLength, int numSides) : base(numSides) {
        SideLength = sidelength; 
        // NumSides will be handled by base class ctor
    }

    // ctor overload with fixed number of sides for squares
    public Square (int sideLength) : this(sideLength, 4) {
    }
}
```